# Make daemon start up with Linux

Tags: linux, startup, daemon

I'm writing a simple daemon application using C/C++ and I want it to start when Linux starts up.

I have tried to modify `/etc/init.d/skeleton` to add a script into the init.d directory as follows

1. added my daemon application in `/usr/sbin/` directory and changed `NAME=myDaemon`
2. write `update-rc.d myDaemon default` in Terminal
3. and it added symbolic links to `rc#.d` directories

But it didn't work.

My second try was to modify `rc.local` as

```
/usr/sbin/myDaemon start
```

But this didn't work either.

How can I make my daemon start with the OS? I want to do everything programmatically.

I use Ubuntu 10.10 but if there exists a general solution for all distributions, that would be great!

Answer (score 9):

You don't *modify* the `/etc/init.d/skeleton` file. You *copy* it to a new file `/etc/init.d/mamoudservice` (replace `mamoudservice` with a more suitable name) and then you *edit* that new file appropriately.

Then you add a symlink from `/etc/rc2.d/S99mamoudservice` to `/etc/init.d/mamoudservice` etc.

Use e.g.

```
   /bin/bash -vx /etc/init.d/mamoudservice start
```

to understand how the `bash` shell is interpreting your script.

If your daemon program `/usr/sbin/mamouddaemon` is coded in C or in C++, I suggest using [openlog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog) and `syslog` inside, at least to get debugging messages (don't output to `stderr` or `stdout` in a daemon, it could go nowhere).

An alternative to having your `/etc/init.d/mamoudservice` script might be to put a `@reboot` entry in your `crontab`

Comment: how can i modify it excuse me as i told you i just take my first steps on Linux World

Comment: try emacs (or vi, no flame war!)

Comment: i don't ask about what text editor i use but what section/Variable in this file to change

Comment: Oh, can't help you there. There are so many ways to solve a problem in linux, it's great. BTW, welcome to linux! (CopyRight free!)

Comment: Ok. Your real question is how to debug your `/etc/init.d/mamoudservice` script. Try to run `/bin/bash -vx /etc/init.d/mamondservice start` and you'll understand what is happening. On a more general note, learn more about your operating system before adding services to it. We cannot help more because we have no idea of how your `/usr/sbin/mamouddaemon` operate, and which program options it is accepting.

Comment: I improved my answer.

Comment: my daemon application is just the template for any daemon app and it does nothing now

Comment: when i tried this command /bin/bash -vx /etc/init.d/mamondservice start it starts my application now how can i make it execute it when startup

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132 `/etc/init.d/skeleton` is no more.

Answer (score 2):

Try [chkconfig](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html) with the name of your service and then "on."  This must be run as root.

Comment: i don't want to use GUI App or Terminal
if i want so i can use Startup Application Application on Ubuntu

Comment: chkconfig modifies a file so that the indicated service is automatically started the next time you turn your computer on. Trust me, after setting up a CentOS server cluster, this is how you do it.

Comment: @Ma7moud El-Naggar: `chkconfig` creates various symlinks in `/etc/rc\d.d/` for you.

Comment: i have already symlinks on rc#.d directories