# Whither /etc/init.d/skeleton?

Tags: debian, sysvinit

Long-standing advice on writing van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts for Debian, from many sources including the *Debian Policy Manual* and answers on StackExchange, until now has been:

> An example on which you can base your `/etc/init.d` scripts is found in `/etc/init.d/skeleton`.

Is this still the case?

Answer (score 7):

## No, `/etc/init.d/skeleton` is no more.

Advice as of 2018 is:

> An example on which you can base your `/etc/init.d` scripts is available in the man page `init-d-script`(5).

systemd developer Michael Biebl and Debian maintainer of van Smoorenbug `rc`+`init` Dmitry Bogatov got together and agreed to remove `/etc/init.d/skeleton`.  The script to use as a template (which unlike the erstwhile `/etc/init.d/skeleton` file does not contain tweaks to make it work on Debian FreeBSD) is now the one that is in the manual.

Note that the Debian template itself changed several years ago, back in 2014. It is now structured far more like an `rc` script in Mewburn `rc` or OpenBSD `rc`, with a shell function library doing most of the work and the main `rc` script content comprising little more than a series of variable assignments in simple cases.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- Petter Reinholdtsen (2014-02-09).  [`init-d-script`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sysvinit-utils/init-d-script.5.en.html). *File formats manual*. Debian.
- Olaf van der Spek (2008-02-09). *[skeleton: Move skeleton code into a file that other scripts can include](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=464854)*. Debian bug #464854.
- Petter Reinholdtsen (2014-02-09).  *[New `init.d` script interpreter `/lib/init/init-d-script`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/commit/fbf700964e86953d2c573229c39482db0b9e1eb7)*.  sysvinit package.  Debian.
- Michael Biebl (2018-11-07). *[Please move `/etc/init.d/skeleton`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913154)*. Debian bug #913154.
- Dmitry Bogatov (2018-11-09). *[debian-policy: Update location of example `init.d` script](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913295)*. Debian bug #913295.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [*A side-by-side look at run scripts and service units.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/run-scripts-and-service-units-side-by-side.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The known problems with System 5 `rc`*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/system-5-rc-problems.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Luke Mewburn (2001). [The Design and Implementation of the NetBSD `rc.d` system](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix01/freenix01/full_papers/mewburn/mewburn_html/)" ([Author's copy](http://www.mewburn.net/luke/papers/rc.d.pdf)) *Proceedings of the 2001 Annual Technical Conference*. Usenix. pp. 69–80.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472993/5132