# init.d based on a bash script fails, why?

Tags: sysvinit

I have this `init.d` script (`/etc/init.d/ctrlme`):

```
#!/lib/init/init-d-script

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ctrlme
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: ctrlme
# Description:       ctrlme
### END INIT INFO

# sudo cp -v /home/gigikent/bin/init.d-services/ctrlme /etc/init.d/; sudo chown root: /etc/init.d/ctrlme
#
# https://www.pks.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.1/suselinux-manual_en/manual/sec.boot.init.html   
#

NAME=ctrlme
PIDFILE=/run/ctrlme.pid
DAEMON=/bin/bash -c '/home/gigikent/x.sh ctrlme'
DESC=ctrlme

# . /lib/lsb/init-functions
# 
# case "$1" in
#   start)
#         /home/gigikent/x.sh ctrlme
#     ;;
#   stop|restart|force-reload) 
#         exit 0
#     ;;
#   *) echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2; exit 1 ;;
# esac
```

which when started fails with:

```
Jun 16 18:57:13 gigikent.go.ro ctrlme[28454]: /lib/init/init-d-script: 20: /etc/init.d/ctrlme: -c: not found
Jun 16 18:57:13 gigikent.go.ro systemd[1]: ctrlme.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit ctrlme.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

Running `/bin/bash -c '/home/gigikent/x.sh ctrlme'` command works as expected.
Why this happens and how should I solve the problem?

System info:
Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Quote your variables (assignments) !! Use: `DAEMON="/bin/bash -c '/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme'"`

Comment: Please paste your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and you will find several issues (and a simple description of what the problem is).

Comment: As I already mentioned the `x.sh` script is running fine when executed directly. When using DAEMON="..." I get `basename: extra operand ‘'/home/adr/x.sh’`.

Comment: When `executed directly` you are using a **bash** shell: `/bin/bash -c '/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme'` but the shell-bang (Please use shellcheck to confirm) is invalid, or (at least) doesn't set the shell to bash.

Comment: Are you sure? check this: `sudo grep -nr '#!/lib/init/init-d-script' /etc/init.d` yields
`/etc/init.d/whoopsie:1:#!/lib/init/init-d-script`

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The `init-d-script` is not a shell. I invite you to learn the basics.

Comment: What happens when you execute your script as: `/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme`

Comment: Running `/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme` works as expected; be aware that `x.sh` starts with `#!/bin/bash`. I again mention that running `/bin/bash -c '/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme'` also works as expected. I agree `#!/lib/init/init-d-script` (used by `/etc/init.d/ctrlme`) is odd but on the other hand seems to function well.

Comment: Can a shell script be an interpreter?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor according to `man init-d-script`, yes the script can be used as an interpreter. “init-d-script - interpreter for short and simple init.d scripts. … This is a simple example on how init-d-script can be used to start and stop a daemon with PID file support: `#!/lib/init/init-d-script` …”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> DAEMON=/bin/bash -c '/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme'
> ```

This should be:

```
DAEMON="/bin/bash" 
DAEMON_ARGS="'/home/adr/x.sh ctrlme'"
```

or, better yet:

```
DAEMON="/home/adr/x.sh" 
DAEMON_ARGS="ctrlme"
```

## Further reading

- [Whither /etc/init.d/skeleton?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/480896/5132)

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the `/lib/init/init-d-script` source one observes:

```
do_start_cmd() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet ${PIDFILE:+--pidfile ${PIDFILE}} \
        $START_ARGS \
        --startas $DAEMON --name $NAME --exec $DAEMON --test
```

which with scripts (e.g. bash scripts) this won't work because according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html `DAEMON` should be a `pathname`:

```
-a, --startas pathname
        With --start, start the process specified by pathname.  If not
        specified, defaults to the argument given to --exec.
```

Also one could just compare the above usage of `start-stop-daemon` with the one from `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, e.g.:

```
start_daemon () {
    ...
    exec="$1"; shift
    ...
    if [ "$force" ]; then
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon $args \
        --chdir "$PWD" --startas $exec --pidfile /dev/null -- "$@"
    ...
```

When using `start_daemon` with e.g.:

```
start_daemon -p /run/ctrlme.pid /bin/bash /home/adr/x.sh ctrlme
```

than `$exec` would be `/bin/bash` while `"$@"` would be `/home/adr/x.sh` + `ctrlme` meaning that when not having a `pathname` one would have to use `start_daemon()` instead of `/lib/init/init-d-script` with its `DAEMON` variable.

**UPDATE**

I let this answer too because better highlights the issue & solution. On the other hand be aware that this part of conclusion is false:

> when not having a `pathname` one would have to use
>   `start_daemon()` instead of `/lib/init/init-d-script`

Indeed one could use `DAEMON` with `DAEMON_ARGS` as mentioned by the accepted answer. This is true because `do_start_cmd()` calls `start-stop-daemon` 2 times where the 2nd call is benefiting of `DAEMON_ARGS`:

```
do_start_cmd() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet ${PIDFILE:+--pidfile ${PIDFILE}} \
        $START_ARGS \
        --startas $DAEMON --name $NAME --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet ${PIDFILE:+--pidfile ${PIDFILE}} \
        $START_ARGS \
        --startas $DAEMON --name $NAME --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
```

Comment: The script fails because it is missing quotes. It makes the (incorrect?) assumption that the DAEMON variable will contain **no spaces**.

Comment: I tried with quotes too having the same result. Besides, as one can see the documentation asks for a pathname.