# what is apache-htcacheclean for, and why is it in /etc/init.d/

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, sysvinit

I have installed `apache2` package in Debian. In addition to the startup script `/etc/init.d/apache2`, there is also another one:

```
/etc/init.d/apache-htcacheclean
```

What is the purpose of this script? The description says:

```
# Short-Description: Cache cleaner process for Apache2 web server
# Description:       Start the htcacheclean helper
#  This script will start htcacheclean which will periodically scan the
#  cache directory of Apache2's mod_cache_disk and remove outdated files.
```

so it looks like some maintenance script that cleans cache. Why is it then in `/etc/init.d/`, where usually only startup scripts reside.

Also the format of this script looks different from standard startup script.

So I am confused;

1. why is it in `/etc/init.d/`
2. what does it do
3. who is calling this script
4. how can I check whether I am actually using this script
5. where is the "cache directory of Apache2's mod_cache_disk", that is mentioned in the description
6. what will happen if I delete it from `/etc/init.d/` ?

As should be clear from my question, I am using sysvinit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## by default

By default, this script serves no function.  The existence of the [`apache-htcacheclean.service`](https://sources.debian.org/src/apache2/2.4.38-3+deb10u3/debian/apache2.apache-htcacheclean.service/) unit file completely obviates its entire function, and systemd ignores it.

## when the van Smoorenburg system is in use

When the van Smoorenburg `init`+`rc` system is in use, this script does *exactly what the comment says*: it starts the [`htcacheclean`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htcacheclean.html) program, which has doco supplied by Apache.  It is invoked by van Smoorenburg `rc` *in the same usual way that the other `rc` scripts are*, as a result of the usual symbolic link farm (or file-rc file) maintained for that system in `/etc/rc*.d/`.  It is *just like other modern-form van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts*, whose "new" (as of 2014) format is documented in the manual.

And where the cache directory is, *is a configuration parameter for the service, set by you* (with a default), named `HTCACHECLEAN_PATH`.

## Further reading

- `man -s 5 init-d-script`
- `man -s 8 htcacheclean`
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132